# Hive error while creating partitioned view

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I got a 'log' table which is currently partitioned by year, month and day. I'm looking to create a partitioned view on top of 'log' table but running into this error:

```
hive> CREATE VIEW log_view PARTITIONED ON (pagename,year,month,day) AS SELECT pagename, year,month,day,uid,properties FROM log; 

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10093]: Rightmost columns in view output do not match PARTITIONED ON clause
```

Whats the right way to create a partitioned view?

Comment: Do you have a particular need for a partitioned view, or can you have a partitioned table that the view selects from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this on..

```
 CREATE VIEW log_view PARTITIONED ON (pagename,year,month,day) AS SELECT uid,properties,pagename, year,month,day FROM log;
```

Reason is partition columns must be last in select  statement query.